# Can I authorize my token in params with Pundit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

We have a model that gets its own access token, like when sharing a google doc or dropbox folder.

Can we use the params[:token] with Pundit's authorize method?  It's a little strange to have that part in the controller and not in the policy.

Answer (score 1):

Pundit is authorization for Ruby objects. You don't authorize a string token, you authorize the related model.

```
@doc = Document.find_by(token: params[:token])

authorize @doc, :show?
```